# pickerview action on change

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uipickerview

I would like to change a label, while the value of a picker view was changed.

The problem is that I can not create an action by dropping the picker view to the code. Is this impossible?

With my datepicker, I can do it like that:

```
    @IBAction func ChangeDatePicker(sender: AnyObject) {

    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    var strDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(DatePicker.date)

    DateLabel.text = "\(strDate) Uhr"
}
```

Answer (score 11):

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    print(myPickerViewData[row])
}
```

Tutorial here: http://makeapppie.com/tag/uipickerview-in-swift/

Answer (score 0):

You must set action in this way.If picker value changed it calls your function.

```
DatePicker.addTarget(self, action: Selector("ChangeDatePicker:"), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
```

Comment: sry, but you dont understand me. it is not a datepicker. its a picker view.

Comment: so i get with the code above this error: datepicker has not a member addTarget

Comment: Target-action only work for UIControl, UIPickerView doesn't seem to be a UIControl. But UIDatePicker is, you can confirm from Apple doc. It seemed reasonable to me that UIPickerView should have been a UIControl. Not sure why they don't make it so.